# Blender alpha mask transparency for Source usage?

Tags: transparency

I'm converting a model from fbx to smd, and I'm writing the files to make it compatible with Source.  However, I've only ever worked with textures that are already transparent.  But with this model it comes with a solid black background on the texture itself and uses and alpha mask, which I don't think source can use.  Is there any way to get rid of the background of the texture via the alpha mask and get the main texture file transparent?

[image: Alpha Mask]

Comment: you can plug the Image Texture into the Alpha socket of the Principled BSDF, put a ColorRamp between the 2 nodes to vary the alpha intensity, then render with the film set as Transparent?

Comment: Thank you moonbots, but I think I got it! I opened photoshop and just attached the above alpha mask as a mask to the original texture and output that as PNG. Works like a charm!